# utility of using ALL in --tcp-flags in iptables rule

Tags: linux, networking, security, iptables, tcp

I m wondering what is the difference between the following 2 `--tcp-flags` rules:

1)

```
-p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,FIN,RST SYN,FIN,RST
```

2)

```
-p tcp --tcp-flags ALL SYN,FIN,RST
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first proposition means : Are SYN and FIN and RST flags at 1 ? Whatever the value of the other flags.

The second proposition means: Are SYN at 1 and ACK at 0 and FIN at 1 and RST at 1 and URG at 0 and PSH at 0 ?